# C++ File Input start from next line

Tags: c++, arrays, file, input, output

I have to write a program that read a file like that:
**7

5 6 4 2 1 3 8**
The first line indicates how many people there are and the second the height of each one. I managed to read the first line and store in a variable, but how can i proceed to the second read each integer individually (they are separated with spaces)

```
using namespace std;

int rowNum;


int main()
{
    fstream myfile;
    string rowNumT;

    myfile.open ("xxx_in.txt",ios::in | ios::out);
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        while(getline(myfile,rowNumT)){
            //cout << rowNumT ;
            istringstream (rowNumT) >> rowNum;
            cout << rowNum ;//how many children in integer form

        }
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    int heights[rowNum];

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't even need `getline` for this. Just read one number at a time straight from the file.

Answer (score 2):

No need to parse string and extra heights, simple use :-

```
int npeople ;
int height ;
// std::vector<int> heights ; // Use std::vector
myfile >> npeople ;

while ( myfile >> height )
{
   // Use height ;
   // heights.push_back ( height );
}
```

OR

```
myfile >> npeople ;
std::vector<int> heights ;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int>( myfile ), 
           std::istream_iterator<int>(),
           std::back_inserter( heights )
          ) ;
```

Also, can use C++11 to achieve following :

```
myfile >> npeople ;
std::vector<int> heights { std::istream_iterator<int>( myfile ), 
                           std::istream_iterator<int>() 
                         };
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to read & store 2nd line ( after getting number from first line ).

```
std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
std::string line;

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  int n;
  std::vector<int> v;

  while (iss >> n)
  {
    v.push_back(n);
  }
}
```